# WinUI3: Binding Text Block width to width of a grid column in code-behind

Tags: c#, binding, winui-3

So, I want to bind the width of my text block to the actual width of a grid column. The text block is generated in the code behind so the binding must be declared there as well.

The binding code is as follows:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = pageWidth;
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth");
binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(textBlock, TextBlock.WidthProperty, binding);
```

textBlock is my text and pageWidth is just a column definition. When I run the application, the text block doesn't appear. I'm assuming the binding is setting the width to 0.

Using `Debug.WriteLine(pageWidth.ActualWidth);` I can see that when the binding is declared the actual width of pageWidth is 0, but that's just because it hasn't been rendered yet, since it's binded surely the text block's width should update when the pageWidth is rendered?

I also tried establishing the binding using `textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.WidthProperty, binding);` as well but still get the same result.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to binding for this. The `TextBox` should extend itself.

This code works:

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="BindingTests.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:BindingTests"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace BindingTests;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock textBlock1 = new()
        {
            Text = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20",
        };

        Grid.SetColumn(textBlock1, 0);
        this.RootGrid.Children.Add(textBlock1);

        TextBlock textBlock2 = new()
        {
            Text = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z",
        };

        Grid.SetColumn(textBlock2, 1);
        this.RootGrid.Children.Add(textBlock2);
    }
}
```